# using vlookup with excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a excel sheet tab with following values

```
Class Date
A    07/07/2000
B    08/07/2012
C    09/10/2011
```

I have a second tab with the following values

```
Class Student Date
A    1
A    2
B    3
B    1
C    1
```

I would like to add the date from sheet1 to sheet2. I know I can use `VLOOKUP` but can't figure out how ! `:-(`

Comment: Please note that in future Excel formula questions should be asked at Super User rather than Stack Ovefflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the first sheet is Sheet1 with Class in column A and Date in column B then try this formula in C2 of your second sheet

`=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!A$2:B$10,2,0)`

copy that down to C6

Answer (score 1):

In Sheet2, C2: `=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!A:B,2,FALSE)` and copy down